# Bind to self class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In XAML, how do I bind the `DataContext` to the overall `Page's` class so I can access its own properties?

Meaning if I have the following XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="EasyWalk.UI.DetailPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:EasyWalk.UI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"> <!--This doesnt work-->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

How do I bind that grid to the same `DetailPage` that the XAML using (binding to its own class)? I want to be able to access members of that class (itself) in the XAML.

Meaning, I want to be able to access the `TestString` member of `DetailPage`:

```
 public sealed partial class DetailPage: Page
    {
        private string testString;

        public String TestString
        {
            get { return this.testString; }
        }

        public EWRODetailPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
```

Somewhere in my XAML like this:

```
<TextBox Text = "{Binding TestString}"/>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: While this is possible, I strongly urge you to create a separate class to use as a view-model and bind to that as your data context. Here's an overview of the MVVM pattern in case you are unfamiliar. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just use a Binding with nothing in it:

```
DataContext="{Binding }"
```

Alternatively, you can use a period to denote "self" in Bindings:

```
DataContext="{Binding .}"
```

The MSDN page documents both of these on [Binding.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Set DataContext in code behind

```
public sealed partial class DetailPage: Page
{
    private string testString;

    public String TestString
    {
        get { return this.testString; }
    }

    public EWRODetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }    
}
```

And remove this line: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Please note: DetailPage class doesn't implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so if you change TestString value UI will not updated